# Column 'NroBoleta' in field list is ambiguous

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo un error en el la siguiente consulta de sql, y no se a que se refiere, la consulta que estoy haciendo es esta:

```
SELECT NroBoleta,FechaAlquiler,idPelicula,PrecioAlquilado 
FROM Boleta,detalleBoleta

CREATE TABLE Pelicula(
idPelicula varchar(5) not null,
titulo varchar(80) not null,
tipo enum('Comedia', 'Accion', 'Terror', 'Drama') default "Comedia" not null,
categoria enum ('Estreno', 'Normal', 'Clasico') default "Estreno" not null,
actorPrincipal varchar(50) not null,
precioActual int(11) not null,
stock int(11) not null,
saldo int(11) not null,
constraint pk_pelicula primary key (idPelicula)
);

CREATE TABLE Cliente(
idCliente varchar(12) not null,
nombre varchar(50) not null,
apellido1 varchar(50) not null,
apellido2 varchar(50) not null,
documento int(11) not null,
direccion varchar(80) not null,
telefono varchar(10) not null,
celular varchar(10) not null,
constraint pk_cliente primary key (idCliente)
);

CREATE TABLE Boleta(
NroBoleta varchar(5) not null,
FechaAlquiler datetime not null,
idCliente varchar(12) not null,
constraint pk_boleta primary key (NroBoleta),
constraint fk_idCliente foreign key (idCliente) references Cliente (idCliente)
);

CREATE TABLE detalleBoleta(
NroBoleta varchar(5) not null,
idPelicula varchar(5) not null,
precioAlquilado int(11) not null,
devuelto enum('SI', 'NO') not null,
fechaDevolucion datetime not null,
diasMora int(11) not null,
constraint fk_NroBoleta foreign key (NroBoleta) references Boleta (NroBoleta),
constraint fk_idPelicula foreign key (idPelicula) references Pelicula
(idPelicula)
);
```

Aquí esta la estructura de las tablas, aún no se mucho de esto pero hago lo que puedo, no se por donde vayan los tiros del error, gracias de antemano.

No se que mas decir, me pide que de mas información pero no se que mas información dar, así que estoy escribiendo lo que sea, de verdad no se nada de ese error.

Comment: En ambas tablas de tu select tenes nroboleta, agrega Boleta.NroBoleta en el select. El error es porque no sabe de cual tabla devolver el dato.

Comment: @BetaM Ok gracias